# Writing Cue Data into RF64 WAV File

Tags: audio, wav, file-format

I'm not entirely sure if StackOverflow is the right site for this question, but I looked at all the other sites in the StackExchange network and none of those seemed more suitable, so apologies if this is not a StackOverflowy enough question.

Anyway, I'm working on making a pretty bare-bones WAV file writer.  In addition to the usual metadata required for playback, I need to be able to add cues at arbitrary points in the file, but I ran into trouble with files over 4GB.  I understand there are multiple approaches to getting larger WAV files, but the approach I would like to take is to use the RF64 WAV file format.  I ran into trouble with the cue structs because these of course use 32-bit sample position offsets which limit cue markers to the first ~4 billion **samples** but not after.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

**EDIT 1:** I confused sample offset with data.  The cue chunk uses sample offsets to position cue points, which may allow this to be used without modification in files over 4GB (e.g. there are multiple channels in the file).  The problem remains for files containing more than 4 billion samples.  I understand this is a high threshold, but I also don't want to impose a limit on audio length if I don't have to.

**EDIT 2:** After some experimentation with large .wav files in Adobe Audition 6, I figured out that Audition side-steps this limitation by generating a .xmp file with XML-like data when saving a sufficiently large .wav file.  However, I would still like to implement cues in as standardized a way a possible within a single .wav file if possible.

Comment: It is possible that Audition is exporting in a [Broadcast Extension WAV format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_Wave_Format). The suggested extension is `.bwf` but it is not uncommon for programmes to export using `.wav`. Check to see if `bext` appears in the header.

Comment: Apologies, also should have made this clear. Rf54 and Broadcast Extension wavs were partly designed to overcome the 4GB limit. If you are hitting a 4GB limit then sadly it would appear your implementation of the standard is not quite correct. [Have a read of the standard to double check your implementation](https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bs/R-REC-BS.2088-1-201910-I!!PDF-E.pdf)

Comment: The problem is that I'm not sure how to properly handle the sample offset field in the cue chunk, not that I can't store more than 4GB worth of audio data.  I looked at the binary of the WAV file that Audition generated and I can confirm that it is not using BWF but RF64.  However, I did find that Audition stuck their cue chunk in an XML tag at the end of the file -- it was a standard WAV cue chunk which was fine because there were fewer than 4 billion samples (there were multiple channels).  I'll need to get a file with more than 4 billion samples and see what happens then...

Comment: Section 2.4 of the standard linked above should have you covered

Comment: For a more in-depth in might be worthwhile including a simple programme that generates a dummy wav file and then tries to parse it. That would allow th community to see a little more of the underlying logic of what you are doing and where you might be diverging from the standard.